# Using drawer navigation and stack navigation at the same time

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I am trying to nest a stack navigation inside a drawer navigation on snack expo. I asked this question before and was told to do it all over again.  I did and still got errors.  Initially I used a class, so I tried using a function instead . I would really appreciate if someone could explain what am I doing wrong? I can also post the link to my project if this helps https://snack.expo.io/@andreeam/it-in-the-valley

The error I get is

```
Device: (0:0) Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
  Evaluating module://react-native-screens.js
  Evaluating module://@react-navigation/drawer.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

Thank you

This is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import ForgotPassword from './components/ForgotPassword';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Advertisers from './components/advertisers';
import Adverts from './components/Adverts';
import Stats from './components/Stats';
import Plans from './components/Plans';
import About from './components/about';
import ManageAdvert from './components/ManageAdvert';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Root () {
     return (
  <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SignIn"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2d3436'},
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold'}
      }}>


      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Reset your password" 
        component={ForgotPassword} 
        options={
          {title: 'Reset your password'},
          {headerLeft: null} 
        } 
        />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="SignIn" 
        component={SignIn} 
        options = {
          {headerShown: false,
          title: 'SignOut'}
        }
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
       name="Dashboard" 
       component={Dashboard} 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Advertisers" 
        component={Advertisers} 
        options={
          {title: 'Advertisers'}
        } 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Adverts" 
        component={Adverts} 
        options={
          {title: 'Adverts'}
        } 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Stats" 
        component={Stats} 
        options={
          {title: 'Stats'}
        } 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Plans" 
        component={Plans} 
        options={
          {title: 'Plans'}
        } 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Manage Adverts" 
        component={ManageAdvert} 
        options={
          {title: 'Manage Adverts'}
        } 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Root">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed that, see snack here => https://snack.expo.io/@mustafaskir/ee857b

just updated packages in package.json, should fix that

here's what packages i updated, and i have to republish in my acc

```
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7"
```